# Get the value of textbox then pass to another modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I want to get the value of a textbox (the value of order_id, to be more specific) from ordermodal.php then pass it to ordermodal2.php. In order to use it in my query.

This is my code for ordermodal.php

```
include_once 'ordermodal2.php';

/** *ordermodal.php **/

 $id = "";
 $order_date = "";
 $order_time = "";
 $order_id = "";
 $order_deliverCharge = "";
 $order_status = "";
 $order_totalAmount= ""; 
 $coordinates = "";
 $driver_number = "";
 $address = "";


 $food_name="";
 $special_request="";
 $quantity="";
 $amount="";
 $orders="";

         ?>

         <!-- MODALS --> <!-- DETAILS --> 
         <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="z-index: 1400;">
         <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
         <div class="modal-content">
        <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
         <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><center>&times;</button>
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="titleModal">Order Information</h4>
     </div>
         <div class="modal-body"> 

  <div class="form-group">
 <label for="order_id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Order ID</label>
 <div class="col-lg-3"> 
 <input type="text" input style="width:500px" class="form-control" name="ORDER_ID" id="ORDER_ID" placeholder="" value="" required="required" readonly> 
</div>
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">User ID</label>
 <div class="col-lg-3"> 
 <input type="text" input style="width:500px" class="form-control" name="user_id" id="user_id" placeholder="" value="" required="required" readonly> 
 </div> 
 </div>

  <div class="form-group">
 <label for="order_date" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Order Date</label>
 <div class="col-lg-3"> 
 <input type="text" input style="width:500px" class="form-control" name="order_date" id="order_date" placeholder="" value="" required="required" readonly> 
 </div> 
 </div>

  <div class="form-group">
 <label for="order_time" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Order Time</label>
 <div class="col-lg-3"> 
 <input type="text" input style="width:500px" class="form-control" name="order_time" id="order_time" placeholder="" value="" required="required" readonly> 
 </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="form-group"> 
 <label for="order_deliverCharge" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Delivery Charge</label>
 <div class="col-lg-3"> 
 <input type="text" input style="width:500px" class="form-control" name="order_deliveryCharge" id="order_deliveryCharge" placeholder="" value="" required="required" readonly>
 </div> 
 </div> 

  <div class="form-group"> 
 <label for="order_totalAmount" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total Amount</label>
 <div class="col-lg-3"> 
 <input type="text" input style="width:500px" class="form-control" name="order_totalAmount" id="order_totalAmount" placeholder="" value="" required="required" readonly>
 </div> 
 </div> 

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label> 
 <div class="col-lg-3">
 <input type="text" input style="width:500px" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" placeholder="" value="" required="required" readonly>
 </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="coordinates" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Coordinates</label> 
 <div class="col-lg-3">
 <input type="text" input style="width:500px" class="form-control" name="coordinates" id="coordinates" placeholder="" value="" required="required" maxlength="11" readonly>
 </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="driver_number" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Driver Number</label> 
 <div class="col-lg-3">
 <input type="text" input style="width:500px" class="form-control" name="driver_number" id="driver_number" placeholder="" value="" required="required" readonly>
 </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="order_status" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Order Status</label> 
 <div class="col-lg-3">
 <input type="text" input style="width:500px" class="form-control" name="order_status" id="order_status" placeholder="" value="" required="required" readonly>
 </div> 
 </div>

  <?php
$order_id = trim(addslashes($_POST['ORDER_ID']));
$sql = "SELECT food_name, special_request, quantity, amount 
FROM cart_tbl
WHERE order_id=$order_id";
$result = mysqli_query(connection(), $sql);
?>

 <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
 <thead>
 <tr> 
 <th>Food</th>
 <th>Special Request</th>
 <th>Quantity</th>
 <th>Amount</th> 
 </tr>
 </thead> 
 <?php
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["food_name"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["special_request"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["quantity"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["amount"];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>

</table>
 <tbody> 

 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
<button type="submit" input style="background-color:#4CAF50;color:white" name="submitDelivered" id="submitDelivered" class="btn btn-primary " onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to deliver order?')){return false;}" > Delivered </button>
<button type="submit" input style="background-color:#0000FF;color:white" name="submitAccept" id="submitAccept" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to accept order?')){return false;}" > Accept </button>
 <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:black" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myDropdown" onclick="send('<?= $_POST['ORDER_ID'] ?>')"> Send </button> 
 <button type="submit" input style="background-color:#f44336;color:white" name="submitCancel" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel order?')){return false;}">Cancel</button> 
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['submitDelivered'])){  
  $ororder_id = trim(addslashes($_POST['ORDER_ID']));
  $query = "UPDATE order_tbl SET `order_status`='Delivered' WHERE `order_id` = $order_id";
  if (mysqli_query(connection(), $query)) { 
         mysqli_query(connection(), "COMMIT");
         $_SESSION['message'] = "Order Delivered"; } 
         else { 
         $_SESSION['message'] = mysqli_error(connection());
         mysqli_query(connection(), "ROLLBACK");
         }
  }

  if(isset($_POST['submitAccept'])){  
  $order_id = trim(addslashes($_POST['ORDER_ID']));
  $query = "UPDATE order_tbl SET `order_status`='Accepted' WHERE `order_id` = $order_id";
  if (mysqli_query(connection(), $query)) { 
         mysqli_query(connection(), "COMMIT");
         $_SESSION['message'] = "Order Accepted"; } 
         else { 
         $_SESSION['message'] = mysqli_error(connection());
         mysqli_query(connection(), "ROLLBACK");
         }
  }


  if(isset($_POST['submitCancel'])){  
  $order_id = trim(addslashes($_POST['ORDER_ID']));
  $query = "UPDATE order_tbl SET `order_status`='Cancelled' WHERE `order_id` = $order_id";
  if (mysqli_query(connection(), $query)) { 
         mysqli_query(connection(), "COMMIT");
         $_SESSION['message'] = "Order Cancelled"; } 
         else { 
         $_SESSION['message'] = mysqli_error(connection());
         mysqli_query(connection(), "ROLLBACK");
         }
  }

  ?>

 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
<script>
 function send(order_id) { 
 document.getElementById("titleModal2").innerHTML = "Choose Driver";
 document.getElementsByName("ORDER_ID_MODAL_2")[0].setAttribute("value", order_id);
 document.getElementsByName("send")[0].setAttribute("name", "send");
 }
 </script>
```

And this is the code for my ordermodal2.php

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myDropdown" role="dialog" style="z-index: 1600;">
   <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
    <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;   </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="titleModal2">Choose Driver</h4>
    </div>
     <div class="modal-body" >

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="order_id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Order ID</label>
 <div class="col-lg-3"> 
 <input type="text" input style="width:450px" class="form-control" name="ORDER_ID_MODAL_2" id="ORDER_ID_MODAL_2" placeholder="" value="" required="required" readonly> 
</div>
</div>
<strong> Select Driver : </strong> 
<select name="empName"> 
       <option value=""> -----------ALL----------- </option> 
     <?php
 $databaseHost = "localhost"; 
 $databaseUser = "";
 $databasePassword = "";
 $databaseName = "";

      $con=mysql_connect($databaseHost ,$databaseUser ,$databasePassword )or die ('Connection Error');
      mysql_select_db("",$con) or die ('Database Error');
         $dd_res=mysql_query("SELECT driver_number FROM driver_tbl");
         while($r=mysql_fetch_row($dd_res))
         { 
               echo "<option value='$r[0]'> $r[0] </option>";
         }
     ?>
</select>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" input style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:black" name="send" class="btn btn-primary"onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to send order?')){return false;}" >Confirm!</button>
    <?php

 if(isset($_POST['send'])){  
  $order_id = trim(addslashes($_POST['ORDER_ID_MODAL_2']));
  $query = "UPDATE order_tbl SET `order_status`='Dispatched' WHERE `order_id` = $order_id";
  if (mysqli_query(connection(), $query)) { 
         mysqli_query(connection(), "COMMIT");
         $_SESSION['message'] = "Order Dispatched"; } 
         else { 
         $_SESSION['message'] = mysqli_error(connection());
         mysqli_query(connection(), "ROLLBACK");
         }
  }
?>
    </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The output will be: when I click the send button in ordermodal then the ordermodal2 will popup obviously,then the Order Id textbox have a value in it already when send button from ordermodal is clicked(the value is same with the ordermodal.php) then when i click the send button in ordermodal2(this is where i need that value) it will change the driver status to dispatched. I hope you can help me with my problem. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

From reading your code, it looks like it should be simple.....

Change

```
document.getElementsByName("ORDER_ID_MODAL_2")[0].setAttribute("value", order_id);
```

To

```
document.getElementsByName("ORDER_ID_MODAL_2")[0].value('<?php echo $order_id?>');
```

Comment: What do you see in the POST data?  (put a print_r($_POST) at the top of ordermodal2.php) - To set your $order_id, you must have $_POST['send'] set, though your element with name="send" is a button with an onclick function, so I'm not seeing where you are setting "send" (perhaps you didn't include all the code? (this looks like bootstrap code without headers and maybe some other stuff, though you didn't say - it might help if you could be more clear on what other things are involved)